# Processing form in modal window with Vue js, Symfony and Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony4, semantic-ui

Iam trying to make an application using Symfony4, Semantic UI and Vue js. Now Iam struggling making the Vue js working on elements inside modal window from Semantic.

I have some input fields from Symfony Form builder inside Semantic modal. I want to prevent default action on submit button - form has `v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"` attribute.
onSubmit function is just `e.preventDefault()` code.

When I open modal and try to click on that button, it just ignore that code and reload page as it thinks I clicked submit button (which I did but I want to call that onSubmit method in Vue).

Can someone help how to make it working? Thanks.

Code as twig template:

```
<a class="ui button add-client-button" @click="openModal">
  <i class="plus icon"></i>
  Add client
</a>

<div class="ui tiny modal add-client">

    <div class="header">Add client</div>
         <div class="content">

         {{ form_start(client_form, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'ui form', 'v-on:submit.prevent' : 'onSubmit' }} ) }}
    ...some form inputs...
         </div>
    <div class="actions">
            <button class="ui black deny button">Close</button>
            <button class="ui button add-client-modal-button" @click="onSubmit">Add</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Code Vue js:

```
new Vue({
delimiters: ['@{', '}'],
el: '#app',
data: {
    modalDom: null
},
mounted: function() {
    this.modalDom = $('.ui.tiny.modal.add-client').modal({ inverted: false, closable: false });
},
methods: {
onSubmit: function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hey')
},
openModal: function()
{
    this.modalDom.modal('show');
}
});
```

whole code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/D7ooyW7j

Comment: Can you please post the entire code, so we can help you? Thank u.

Comment: yea, sure, i updated original post

Comment: Is there an element with `id="app"` that contains your form? Also, are you getting any errors? It looks like you may be missing one `}` around your `methods`.

Comment: You could just put the prevent on the click handler `@click.prevent="onSubmit" `

Comment: what is interesting, when i put all form stuff out of modal, it works. could be something with fact than modal is not presented on page load in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work. I have declared modal instance twice, firstly in jQuery and that was the issue - it overwrite my second instance in Vue. 
I deleted the modal declaration in jQuery and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `el: '#app'` in Vue, you need a wrapping element with id="app"

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- all of your html / template here... -->
</div>
```

And it looks like your `methods` attribute is missing a closing brace `}`:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function (e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('hey')
    },
    openModal: function()
    {
      this.modalDom.modal('show');
    }
  } // <-- missing
});
```

And I'm not sure exactly what `form_start()` is doing, but as long as you get something like this it should be fine:

```
<form class="ui form" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <!-- inputs -->
</form>
```

Comment: i forgot attach that part of code with `id=app`. form_start is just symfony method of generating exactly this `<form name="client" method="post" class="ui form" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">` - that's what i got. here i provide the whole code https://www.codepile.net/pile/D7ooyW7j. and still it do not work.

Comment: In that case I'd just recommend stripping down to the most basic html & js to see if you can get that to work, and start adding features back in until it breaks.